# Need help understanding how to initialize classes in tkinter python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm creating a program that can trade currency using the binance API.
It works as intended (irrelevant code not included)
My problem is that I now want to make is possible to create several instances of the class Trade, in new pop up windows. I'm having trouble understanding how to achieve this in terms of creating new instances of the class Trade. Also I'm pretty sure that my use of self: self = Trade(top) dosen't make any sense (even though it works).

To sum it up:
I want to be able to click a button that starts a new instance of Trade(), so that I can use the methods in the class for two different trading routines at the same time in the same instance of the program. How?

I'll appreciate any form of help, including suggesting me to read up on something.
I'm sorry if im too noob.

Thx in advance.

```
class Trade(Frame):
    stop_trading = False
    amount_orders = 0
    after_id = 0

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

    def change_orders(self):
        if list_variable4.get() == 'TRUE':
            if self.check_open_order() == False or self.amount_orders<2:
                if self.delete_open_orders() == True and self.stop_trading != True:
                    self.create_orders()
    ...

def cron():
    self.amount_orders += 1
    if self.amount_orders > int(trade_cap_box.get(0.0, tk.END)):
        message_window.insert(tk.END,'\nTrade Cycle Cap reached with {} trades'.format(self.amount_orders - 1))
        cap_stop_trading()
    if self.stop_trading != True:
        message_window.insert(tk.END,'\nTrading Cycle Started{}'.format(self.amount_orders))
        interval = int(rate_of_check_box.get(0.0, tk.END))
        print('Trading!')
        self.change_orders()
        self.after_id = top.after(interval*1000*60, cron)

def start_trading():
    self.amount_orders = 0
    self.stop_trading = False
    cron()

top = Tk()
top.geometry("600x500")
top.title('Trade Cron Job')
self = Trade(top)

message_window = Text(top, height=5, width=65)
message_window.place(x = 40,y = 10)

trading_symbol_box = Text(top, height=1, width=20)
trading_symbol_box.place(x = 200,y = 130)
default_trading_symbol = (self.config_data['configs']['symbol'])
if default_trading_symbol:
    trading_symbol_box.insert(END, default_trading_symbol)
else:
    trading_symbol_box.insert(END, "")
trading_symbol_labels = Label(top,  text='Trading Symbol')
trading_symbol_labels.place(x = 40,y = 130)

start_value_box = Text(top, height=1, width=20)
start_value_box.place(x = 200,y = 160)
start_value_box.insert(END, 0)
start_value_labels = Label(top,  text='Start Value To Progress From')
start_value_labels.place(x = 40,y = 160)
and so on...

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about Your indents here, but a few suggestions: `if self.delete_open_orders() == True` can be written as `if self.delete_open_orders()` and similarly this `self.stop_trading != True` can be written as `not self.stop_trading`. About class instances: You just put a variable name and assign a class to it and the class will be initiated: `var_name = ClassName(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `Toplevel`, then add the instance of `Trade` to that window.

```
def new_window():
    window = Toplevel()
    trade_frame = Trade(window)
    trade_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
...
new_window_button = Button(top, text="New Window", command=new_window)
```